# Use any() or all() with break statement logic in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean, conditional-statements, any

This works:

```
def gen():
    yield False
    yield True
    yield oups

if any(gen()):
    print('At least one is True')

# At least one is True
```

But this fails:

```
if any(iter([False, True, oups])):
    print('At least one is True')

# NameError: name 'oups' is not defined
```

Is there a way to transform the second code into the first one without too much effort ?

Comment: what is `oups`, anyway?

Comment: The first will have the same issue. The question doesn't make sense

Comment: The problem is that the `oups` variable doesn't exist. The effort is how much effort goes into making an oups. Lets say its just the text string, then `yield "oups"` does it. Lets say its a global climate model, then more effort is envolved.

Comment: You're relying on (or, rather, being saved by) short-circuiting to avoid an issue with broken code. You're just lucky that the generator doesn't hit the undefined `oups`. Rather than try make a 1-liner, you should be making sure the code works

Comment: The list has to be created before `iter` can return the list iterator that `any` will (lazily) consume.

Comment: @khachik A placeholder for something intentionally not working? Might've helped to spell it `oops`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `gen`, `oups` is just a free variable whose lookup never occurs; `any` stops consuming the generator returned by `gen` before it becomes necessary.

With `iter([False, True, oups])`, however, the list `[False, True, oups]` first has to be fully created so that it can be passed to `iter` to return a list iterator. To do *that*, the lookup of `oups` has to occur, and because it's not defined, we get a `NameError` before `iter`, let alone `any`, even runs. The second code is evaluated the same as

```
t1 = [False, True, oups]  # NameError here
t2 = iter(t1)
if any(t2):
    print('At least one is True')
```

Answer (score 1):

Both pieces of code are technically incorrect, as you didn't define "oups".
This can be shown by exhausting the iterator like so:

```
def gen():
    yield False
    yield True
    yield oups

g = gen()
print(next(g))
print(next(g))
#this next line will break, as it reaches the undefined variable
print(next(g))
```

the any() function will stop running once it hits the first True statement, and will return True. This can be shown by rearranging your yield statements to have the first True after the undefined variable, which will also break:

```
def gen():
    yield False
    yield oups
    yield True

if any(gen()):
    print('At least one is True')
```

Comment: `gen` isn't incorrect, *per se*. As long as you define `oups` before the third call to `next`, no error will occur.

Comment: I guess it depends on your definition of "correct" :) according to this https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html#variables-checker , undefined variables are classified as "errors", making it incorrect, although the code will run.

Comment: It's not undefined until you actually try to look up its value. Replace your `#this next line...` comment with `oups = 3`, and there is no error.